# monitoring windows services status in EC2 with cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Trying to find a solution to monitor windows services in EC2 with cloudwatch.
An example scenario is:

1. windows service A running in EC2 is stopped.
2. After 2 minutes, service A is still stopped.
3. Cloudwatch alarm will be triggered

I tried:
use Cloudwatch log metric filter to filter text like 'service A entered to stopped state' from windows log and trigger the alarm.
But it does not meet the condition in step 2 above. Because windows does not check the service periodically and record it in the windows log.

My question is:
is there a way to use cloudwatch to meet the condition 2 above?
Or is there a better solution to monitor windows services with cloudwatch?

Thanks